# How to check if a combination of values in 2 columns is present in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames. Title and section are two columns among others. 
I need to check if the combination of particular title and section from one data frame is present in the second.

E.g. Data frame `torange` has columns title, s_low, s_high and others; `usc` has columns title and section.

If there's following row in `torange`

```
title   s_low   s_high
  1        1      17
```

the code needs to check in `usc` if a row

```
title   section
 1        1
```

and a row

```
title   section
 1          17
```

exist; and create a new table to write the title, section, and the rest of the columns in `torange` by expanding the range between s_low and s_high in `usc`.

I've written the below code but somehow it doesn't work/ stops after just a few iterations. I'm suspecting that there's something wrong in the counter for 'i', may be a syntax error. Also, it may be something to do with the syntax of `any()`

```
import MySQLdb as db
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.io.sql import frame_query
cnxn = db.connect('127.0.0.1','xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxxxx', charset='utf8', use_unicode=True )
torange = frame_query("SELECT title, s_low, s_high, post, pre, noy, rnum from torange", cnxn)
usc = frame_query("SELECT title, section from usc", cnxn)

i=0
for row in torange:
    t =  torange.title[i]
    s_low = torange.s_low[i]
    s_high = torange.s_high[i]
    for row in usc:
        if (any(usc.title == t) & any(usc.section == s_low)):
            print 't', t, 's_low' , s_low,'i', i
            if (any(usc.title == t) & any(usc.section == s_high)):
                print 't', t, 's_high', s_high, 'i',i
                print i, '*******************match************************'
    i=i+1
```

(Please ignore the priint statements. This is part of a bigger task that I'm doing and prints are used just as checks to see what's happening. )

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole checking and iterations are messed up. You iterate `row` in `usc`, yet your `any()` conditions check `usc`, not `row`. Moreover, `row` is your iterator for both loops. Here is some cleaner starting point:

```
for index, row in torange.iterrows(): 
    t = row['title']
    s_low = row['s_low']
    s_high = row['s_high']
    uscrow = usc[(usc.title == t) & (usc.section == slow)]
    # uscrow now contains all the rows in usc that fulfill your condition.
```

Comment: Moreover, I would always use `iterrows()` and `iteritems()` when iterating through dataframes, just to be sure it actually does what I expect it to.

Comment: very *rarely* should you actually need to iterate. this is a simple application of ``isin``

Comment: @FooBar Thanks for the response. I'm new to pandas, hence the messed up iterations. how can I check for s_high as well in the same statement/otherwise? My result set would have the rows that fullfill both the following conditions  [(usc.title == t) and (usc.section == s_low)] and [(usc.title == t) and (usc.section == s_high)]

Comment: Simply put, both s_low and s_high for a particular title must be present in usc.

Comment: @Jeff how can I iterate while using isin? I've gone through the documentation : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html  how can I pass somany values into it as parameters?

Comment: @j-v: Extending the selection criterion is something that I would expect a learning programmer to come by himself: If you know how to `select if a and b`, `select if a and b and c and d` is derivative. Anyhow, in case you didn't manage to get there by yourself by tomorrow, ping me again.

Comment: @FooBar Sure, I will try to come up with the extension. But before that, When I try to run the above code I'm getting the following error: uscrow = usc[(usc.title == t) and (usc.section == s_low)] .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
I replaced 'and' with '&', now the program runs infinitely. Any clue?

Comment: Whoups, my bad: use `&` instead of `and`.

Comment: Sure. uschigh = uscrow[(usc.title == t)& (usc.section == s_high)] I figure this would be the next step. Does this make sense? I ran it but it returned empty dataframes.

Comment: Well, if it returns empty dataframes, there are no rows satisfying your selection criteria.

Comment: That was implied. Please try to figure "small" stuff out more by yourself. In this case, you can quickly create a dataframe containing two rows and two columns, and check whether you are selecting the proper columns. SO is supposed to help you with approaches and problems, not to hold your hands at every step.

Comment: @FooBar I'm sorry for not being clear. I know the data and it is not supposed to return empty data frames. So, I was wondering where I was going wrong. I'm not able to export uscrow/uschigh to a csv as well. I'm using csv writer <writer.writerow(uscrow)>, it gives me the following error.  raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
KeyError: u'no item named 0'

Comment: This seems to be a new problem on its own. Close this question, open up a new one. But before you do, you should try to debug more on your own. Create 3 lines of a df, to check whether your code works. If it works, try to see what's wrong with your df. Perhaps its string values with a space in the end or so. If you still can't figure out, open a new question, dump 2 or 3 lines that should fulfill the criteria and show your code, and state your expected result.

Comment: Although your behavior is not a borderline case of [1], your behavior shows lack of own actions, such as stated by [2].
 [1]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back?cb=1 [2]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257874/1082349